# Forcing Minimum of 3 Digits?

Tags: php, sql

I was wondering if it is possible to always force a minimum of triple digits from an SQL statement to PHP, I am resonably new to PHP/SQL.

```
$count = $con->num_rows #num_rows currently shows 1
echo "Number of Rows: " .$count #shows "Number of Rows: 1"
```

How would I force it to output "Number of Rows: 001".
But then once it goes into natural four digit numbers, `1000`, then it doesn't force triple digits.

Examples: `001` `010` `100` `1000`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  str_pad ( $count, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

Comment: And this'll stop padding when it hits `1000+` ?

Comment: you mean if e.g., `$count = "1234"`? Then it will return `"1234"`

Answer (score 1):

```
     $newstring = str_pad($string,3,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: does not work, since default is `STR_PAD_RIGHT` and we want `STR_PAD_LEFT`. Also you cannot use the default value for pad-string, since it is `" "`.

Answer (score 0):

> str_pad — Pad a string to a certain length with another string
>
> string str_pad ( string $input , int $pad_length [, string $pad_string = " " [, int $pad_type = STR_PAD_RIGHT ]] )

and more

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php is what you need.